# Adobe Flash - Buttons are only clickable on the corner

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

First i used images for the buttons in my Adobe AIR App, but now i wanted to just use rectangles made in Adobe Flash. But if I use them as button, they are only clickable on the corner, Not on the rectangle surface (Transparent).

Comment: What type is the rectangle? If it is of type `Shape`, it is not an `InteractiveObject` and cannot dispatch events.

Comment: Not enough details in the post to be sure, but one common cause of buttons not reacting to clicks is existence of child objects in the button. Setting mouseChildren=false on the button will fix that.

Comment: Selectable text can mess things up too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rectangle shaped MovieClip symbol within your Button symbol that fills the space of the entire button and make it transparent with `Alpha = 0`.